# Copying values from base class to derived class

Tags: c++

Didnt want to put a really long title, continuing - **without modifying the base class** and **without copying one by one**.

Lets say the base is `CClient`, but I dont want to add or remove anything:

```cpp
class CClient
{
public:
    void (*Connect)();
    void (*Disconnect)();

    bool m_bIsConnected;
};
```

And say this is derived `CClientHook`.

```cpp
class CClientHook : public CClient
{
public:
    bool Setup(bool hook);

    bool m_bIsHooked;
};
```

How can I copy values from `CClient` object to `CClientHook` object safely? Sorry for weird wording.

**EDIT:** To clarify, there are two objects and no, `Connect` and `Disconnect` arent supposed to be methods.

```cpp
CClient g_Client;
CClientHook g_ClientHook;
```

Comment: Note that e.g. `Connect` is a pointer to a *non* member function. It can't point to member function or capturing lambds. To make `Connect` and `Disconnect` more generic use `std::function` like `std::function<void()> Connect;`

Comment: As for your question, what do you mean when you say that you want to "copy values from `CClient` object to `CClientHook` object"? Since `CClientHook` *is a* `CClient` (remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship) all members of `CClient` are also members of `CClientHook`. Please [edit] your question to try and clarify and elaborate. Perhaps even show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
CClient a;
CClientHook b;
```

There are at least two options:

- `static_cast<CClient &>(b) = a;`
- `b.CClient::operator=(a);`

Comment: If you add `using CClient::operator=;` into the sub class, `b = a` works. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EcEj7YKzv